# extract links from a page using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I am new to selenium, and I am studying how to extract what I want using selenium

I want to extract hyperlinks in a webpage, but only those that have specific tags. The hyperlink are all nested in the following structure:

```
<a title="Chris Frye" class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/CnMFrye"><span>Chris Frye</span></a>
```

However, when using tag 'a', I realized that it scrapes other hyperlinks, so I believe I need to condition both tag 'a' and 'class'.

In this case, what is the right strategy? I can't seem to use `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name`, because this is only for a single tag.

The page I want to scrape is : https://www.facebook.com/public/chris-frye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css selector like bellow:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a._32mo')
```

Or use xpath:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='_32mo']")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @song0089 Feel free to accept or/and upvote this answer, if solved the issue :)